# How does the MCU Helicarrier get aircraft back to the hangar?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

The Helicarrier is obviously based on modern supercarriers, like the Nimitz-class. In particular, the flight deck, as with all supercarriers, is angled to allow simultaneous launch and recovery operations.  However, on the Helicarrier, the angled deck section is raised above a straight deck.  Presumably, this is done for rule of cool, as I can't think of any real benefit this would provide, but it leads to an interesting question: when aircraft land on that raised deck, presumably having spent their munitions, how do they get back into the hangar?  Where could an elevator be put without interfering with the launching deck, or could it use a different system?

Comment: https://i.redd.it/2vsgu391wgq21.jpg

Comment: MCU Helicarrier, not comics Helicarrier.

Comment: Isn't the angled part used for launches? I was under the impression that landing took more runway length, especially when you take the need to go around into account.

Comment: @Cadence On a modern aircraft carrier, there are catapults on both portions of the deck. The angled part is used for landings so they can continue to launch off the bow. CATOBAR aircraft only land in the broadest sense of the word - it's more like a precisely controlled crash. The aircraft actually throttle *up* when they hit the deck, so they have the power for that go-around if the wire doesn't catch. You also want them pointed off to the side so they can go into the drink beside the carrier, not in front of it, when multiple failure states align.

Comment: Of course, a failed landing on a Helicarrier is even worse than just a pilot and plane going into the ocean... As somebody comments below, a failed arrest combined with a failure to accelerate is likely to put the aircraft into that forward portside engine.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn’t appear to be any immediate way for the aircraft to get between the two decks that I have noticed. However, there doesn’t necessarily need to be. The aircraft on the rear raised deck have anchoring points and are bolted down when need be as we see in *The Avengers* in the take off scene.

There is also a little “plane park” section of the deck clear of the runway that is used for the planes.

[image: The Helicarrier raises out of the water, the rear deck has one plane in the runway and several parked up off to the side of it in the “parking” section]

However, of note is in the *Marvel Studios Visual Dictionary* is a page on the Helicarrier which makes mention of two “aircraft elevators to hangars” on the lower front deck. There doesn’t appear to be anything similar on the rear deck.

[image: Photo of the Helicarrier page from the Visual Dictionary; it mainly shows a lossy annotated image of a Helicarrier with a few very basic write ups not relevant to the answer]

It also notes that the front deck is used for takeoffs and the angled rear one is used for landings.

It is also worth noting that the Helicarrier has two main vehicles that use the decks: Quinjets and F-35 Lightning IIs. Both of these are STOVL, short take-off and vertical landing, aircraft. As such they can land with precision so it would seem that they *could* take off from one deck and quite easily land on the other, certainly the Quinjet could.

Comment: The anchoring points you mention are also part of modern aircraft carriers so I wouldn't count them as anything special for this.

Comment: @JoeW the only reason I mention them is because there is no way between the two decks for the aircraft on the Helicarrier itself. So it seems they’re used as temporary parking at least.

Comment: FWIW, only the F35-B can land vertically; neither the more common F35-A (Air Force) not the F35-C (Navy - carrier adapted) lands vertically.

Comment: It's not very clear - but in the still from the movie it looks like there are some markings near the front of the upper deck runway which could be a deck-lift? I can't seem to find a better angle/detail of that part of the ship, though.

Comment: If they built it so that overrunning your landing gets you sucked into an engine, there's no reason they wouldn't have put elevators *anywhere at all*.  :-P

Comment: @DavidW In the scene where Thor and the Hulk are fighting in the lab, a SHIELD F-35 goes into hover mode outside the helicarrier to "distract" the Hulk. It has two onboard guns - the real-world A carries one in the port wing root, and the B and C can optionally carry one in a centerline external hardpoint. SHIELD uses a hover-capable F-35, but it is none of the real-world variants.